# a case of vote rigging?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

How is it possible that this question, where it's not even clear what the guy is asking or attempting to do, and ignoring a single request for clarification, has generated a +8 in a mere 39 views (all of these +8 being in a single 24h period), yet the very single answer that was there all along has attracted a mere +1 and zero comments?

[The $http_referer behaves like the $document_uri](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33386997/1122270)

Comment: He [posted it](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458880/http-referer-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-document-uri) on russian SO beforehand

Comment: @user193661, yes, exactly, and it's a big 0 there, because it's not really clear what's being asked at all.

Comment: I'd be happy with your up/down of 1/0 at the moment, considering your Answer starts with `It is not entirely clear what you're asking.` :)

Comment: @Drew, please take a look at my top tag before accusing me of a wash answer. :-)

Comment: I actually read your answer. I liked it. People need to lighten up around here. This is supposed to be enjoyable. We can forget that if we thirst for points. Keep up the good work cnst, seriously.

Comment: @Drew, so you were the only person who voted it up? :-)

Comment: no, but I might, when I get a chance, and back into htaccess and the like, as I am a devops guy.

Comment: All of these votes came in on the last day the bounty was active.  The day that it got moved to the front bounty page.  Not unusual.  Fraudulent votes would normally be cast long before that, no point in upvoting on the last bounty day since that doesn't change visibility or ranking at all.  You don't have a case here.

Answer (score 4):

The OP [offered a bounty on it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332951/ekkertan?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

This often results in extra votes than the norm.

Comment: i've never seen nginx question on a bounty being voted up so high.  especially obscure questions that already have an answer, and no comments nor any other suggestions or even "me, toos".  Why all the positive votes came down in the final day?

Comment: @cnst bounties are sorted by expiry datetime so get more visibility when they are about to expire as they are then on the first page. If you have suspicions flag to a moderator. Don't call out someone that might be perfectly innocent on meta.